# Do I have to have language in URL? [Codeigniter]

Tags: codeigniter, seo, multilingual

I am making a mutli-language site. I have seen that some websites have urls with languages in them like so:

```
http://example.com/en/homepage
```

I hear it is important for SEO, but I was wondering, doesn't that make it more complicated in terms of routing, URI, controllers, rather than just having a session/cookie that holds the desired language?

What are pluses and minuses of each way and which way should I go?

thank you

Comment: SEO is Search Engine Optimization ... at least I had to look it up ;-)

Comment: Search Engines don't generally use cookies. Thus, sessions tend not to exist for them either. So without something in the URL, you'd be limited to serving your content in only one (e.g. the default) language.

Comment: I see, so if your content does need to be googled in both languages, you do need to have it in url. Makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add some lines to your route config and to your core to do what you want.

Here are two links with a lot of information to implement this: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/URI_Language_Identifier/

http://sumonbd.wordpress.com/2009/09/16/develop-multilingual-site-using-codeigniter-i18n-library/